# Student's distriubtion

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

For Student's distribution:
what is the most intuitive argument that for $\nu$ increasing $t_{n-2}$ decreases ?
I do not understand this as $$t_{calc}=\frac{r\sqrt{n-2}}{\sqrt{1-r^2}}$$ increases with larger
$n$.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Note the decay of Student-$t$ probability density function,

Comment: @user10354138 Thank you for your answer. Could you please be more explicit which decay do you mean exactly ? I have added a 3rd snippet of Student's pdf: first the distribution grows and then it goes down. How can I derive from it $\nu>\nu '\implies t_{\nu-2,\alpha}>t_{\nu'-2,\alpha}$? Also, how can the shape of Student's distribution be derived by **logic** and not by a computation ?

Comment: @user10354138 And yet, where can I find the number $63.657$ in that graph for $\nu=1$ and $\gamma=0.995$,say from the top right item in the table: where is $\gamma,\nu$ and $63.657$ ? I'm new to reading from pdf graph.

Comment: @user10354138 And finally, what is the relationship of $$t_{calc}=\frac{r\sqrt{n-2}}{\sqrt{1-r^2}}$$ with $t_{\nu-2,\alpha}$ ?